# Jquery nodeName simple query?

Tags: jquery

I am looking at this code from the jquery api website how I do not understand how it works

I only do not understand how this part works [ 0 ].nodeName, what does the 0 do?

```
        $( "<b></b>" ).html( $( ":root" )[ 0 ].nodeName ).appendTo( "#log" );
```

for the full code please go here   http://api.jquery.com/root-selector/

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` is indexer used with `jQuery` object (collection) that returns the javascript `DOM` object at zero index and you can access `nodeName` which is attribute of DOM object *not* jQuery object. If the selector return more then one element you can use the index to access particular element. Remember it is zero based index so zero is for first element.

```
$(":root")[0].nodeName //For first element
$(":root")[1].nodeName //For second element
```

You can also use [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function instead of indexer `[]`

$(":root").get(0).nodeName //For first element
   $(":root").get(0).nodeName //For second element

Answer (score 0):

1. `$(":root")` is used to select the top most element that is in the code is HTML
2. `$(":root")[0]` is used to select the first element from all of that means there can be more than one element with same tag name.
3. `nodeName` is used to get the name of that tag.

Comment: @pilogicpi why you have post this link. can you let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object returned by e.g. `jQuery( ':root' )` always returns a set of elements, even if there was only one element. You can access each found DOM element via the index.

Or in the words of the jQuery documentation:

> The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a length property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their numeric indices [0] to [length-1]. Note that a jQuery object is not actually a Javascript Array object, so it does not have all the methods of a true Array object such as join().

http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

To find out if there was at least one element found you may use

```
if( jQuery( ':root' ).length > 0 ) { … }
```

MDN has a good overview on DOM Node properties and methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node